# Isolate user directory in nginx and php

Tags: php

I want to create many virtual hosts, each executing php.

But I don't want any particular virtual host to be able to see the user directory of another virtual host.

How can I do this? I just don't know the relevant keyword. I've been searching forever and it seems related to apparmor (for ubuntu).

Comment: you could maybe use CHROOT since this does what you need but on system-user level, i don't know if its possible to run different virtualhost under differents users... my webserver knowledge does not go that far https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot

Comment: yeah i was looking for something more robust, something that would restrict not just files but also other resources like bandwidth, cpu, i/o, etc.